# Arduino-to-Arduino SPI unexpected characters

Tags: arduino, spi

I've been trying to follow the posts on [Nick Gammon's page](http://www.gammon.com.au/spi) which are admittedly a bit old, but seem to be everyone's recommendation for trying out Arduino to Arduino SPI. I'm able to get communications working, but there's a small issue I can't seem to pinpoint. Every once in a while there are three characters that show up in my output that are completely unexpected. **Where are these characters coming from?**

Here is what they are:

```
Hello, world!
Hello, wo&⸮BHello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```

In the second row, you'll see `&⸮B` in place of what should be `rld!\n`.

I have two Name-brand Arduino UNOs both being powered via USB to my computer, and they each have pins 13,12,11, and 10 directly wired to each other. Here's the code I'm using:

The unexpected characters are the same every time, and seemingly show up as UTF-8...the decimal values for those characters amounts to 38, 226, 66, 10. I'm not sure if that has any significance.

**Master:**

```
#include <SPI.h>

void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  SPI.begin ();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);
}

void loop (void)
{
  char c;

  // enable Slave Select
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);    // SS is pin 10

  // send test string

  const char p [14] = "Hello, world!\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    SPI.transfer(p[i]);  
    Serial.print(p[i]);
  }

  // disable Slave Select
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

  delay (2000);
}
```

**Slave:**

```
#include <SPI.h>

volatile char buf [100];
volatile byte pos;
volatile boolean process_it;

void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin (115200);

  // have to send on master in, *slave out*
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);

  // turn on SPI in slave mode
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);
  
  // turn on interrupts
  SPCR |= _BV(SPIE);

  // get ready for an interrupt 
  pos = 0;   // buffer empty
  process_it = false;

  // now turn on interrupts
  //SPI.attachInterrupt();
}


// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
  byte c = SPDR;  // grab byte from SPI Data Register
  if (pos < sizeof buf)
  {
    if (c == '\n') {
      buf [pos++] = '\0';
      process_it = true;
    }
    else{
      buf [pos++] = c;
      
    }
   
  }
}

void loop (void)
{
  if (process_it){
    char * bufp  = buf;
    Serial.println (bufp);
    pos = 0;
    process_it = false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: String `"Hello, world!\n"` is 15 bytes long not 14.

Comment: @gre_gor, I know. I was testing if that affected it. Previously also tested 15 and 16 as well to see if there was any change. No effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that both units were being powered from the same USB Hub, there was a difference in voltage on the GNDs of each Arduino. Jumping the GND pins between the two got rid of the stray characters and strange behavior. D'oh.